# SP2016 ways to deploy

Tags: powershell, 2016, solution-deployment, content-deployment

Finding it hard to locate any documentation on how to/ways to deploy solutions to SP2016 on site. Specifically I mean an established SP2016 (not new install) but development work we have done and now want to put into the dev / live environment.

I understand the primary way is using powershell - specifically Add-SPSolution Install-SPSolution; but does anyone know if there is another way to do this / any alternative methods?

For example can you use visual studio 2017 to deploy straight to sp enviroment? I found an addon SPFastDeploy that allows for individual file deployment. I just want to get a broader view on the possibilities.

Comment: By curiosity, why do you need another way than PowerShell?

Comment: PowerShell is just the simpliest way to do it :)

Comment: We've got a new apprentice whose not familiar with powershell so I've been tasked with finding alternative ways

Comment: I think it would be well worth the time to teach some basic PowerShell cmdlts for SharePoint, there is plenty of good documentation and PowerShell give's by far the best overview when deploying solutions.

Comment: And by far as it goes, they have to be added to SharePoint by PowerShell but can then be retracted/activated using Central Admins UI.